# Can I use css modules in react class based components?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I have to implement css modules for some older React code. But when I try to import CSS modules, I can´t use this class in another files.

Do I have to refactor the code to React Components? Or is there another easier solution?

Code example:

```
import styles from "styles.module.css"

var Greeting = createReactClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h1>Hello</h1>;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, module CSS is also supported in class-based components.

In the module CSS you have to use CSS as an object,

For Example, You have a CSS class for an alert component

```
.alert{
   color:red
}
```

then you can use it in components like this:-

```
import styles from "styles.module.css"

var Alert = createReactClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h1 className={styles.alert}>Hello</h1>;
    }
});
```